# Floating star effect with an animation and UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I need to make a floating star effect with an UIImageView when view load and I put below code a method and call it from viewWillAppear but it doesn't work as I expected. Simply a little star must became large (4 x height and width) and centered but the animation does work reverse. star starts with 4 x height and width and start to became smaller.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3
                      delay:0.1
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{

                     self.dayStar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width * 4, self.view.frame.size.height * 4);
                     self.dayStar.center = self.view.center;

}
```

what do I need to change on my code and where should I put it. Thanks.

Comment: zoom-in/zoom-out or floating?

Comment: both. zoom in/zoom out while floating/floating back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it overrides with another lines. It's all the code where you change dayStar?
For scale use:

```
[self.dayStar setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)]
```